# Is there any learning info about dart vm

Tags: dart

I am interested in dart. I want to know the story behind the dart VM.But I got fewer info about dart vm . Where Can I get some article or tour about dart vm?

Answer (score 1):

You can learn about Dart in the [Language Tour](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour) and [Effective Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart)

There are also some articles about features [specifically related to the vm](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-vm)

Theres also a cool talk about building a compiler for Dart - https://www.infoq.com/presentations/dart-compiler

Comment: Thank you , it's helpful for me.But it seems not a systematic introduction,although dart is open source code.But reading it without help seems  too difficult,i want to read dart vm source code with a systematic introduction

Comment: There are no such articles that I'm aware of.